# How to compare a negative number in pl/sql if statement

Tags: plsql

Here is the complete function

```
 Function GetStatus_TecTrac( inquiry_id IN number )
RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
 status VARCHAR2(12);
  deptId number;
 endDate date;
  BEGIN

 select DEPT_ID, END_DATE into deptId , endDate from (
 select DEPT_ID, END_DATE
  from TB_PROJECT_TRACKING_DURATION tp
  where tp.INQUIRY_ID = inquiry_id
 order by START_DATE desc
 )
 where rownum = 1;


if (deptId = -61 and endDate is not null) then
    status := 'closed';
else
   status := 'open';
end if;

RETURN status;

END;
```

It always returns the status as "closed" on each inquiry_id whatever the value of deptId and endDate is.
Help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.
Farhan

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.  How did you test?

```
SQL> declare
      deptid number := 44;
      enddate date := sysdate;
      status varchar2(10);
    begin
      if (deptId = -61 and endDate is not null) then
        status := 'closed';
      else
        status := 'open';
      end if;

      dbms_output.put_line(status);
    end;
    /
open

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```